# Set default values in SharePoint Columns for a specific document folder

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list, pnp-core-sdk, pnp-framework

I am attempting to set default values for columns in a document list in SharePoint using the PnP.Core SDK. I can successfully set the values and then query them and get the default values back:

```cs
private async Task SetFolderDefaultValues(IFolder folder, MyEvent event)
{
    var defaultColumnValues = new List<DefaultColumnValueOptions>()
    {
        new()
        {
            FolderRelativePath = folder.ServerRelativeUrl,
            FieldInternalName = "Project_Number",
            DefaultValue = event.ProjectId
        },
        // ... other properties
    };
    var list = await _sharePointContext.Web.Lists.GetByServerRelativeUrlAsync(WorkingDirectoryRootRelativePath);
    await list.SetDefaultColumnValuesAsync(defaultColumnValues);
    
    var loadedDefaults = await list.GetDefaultColumnValuesAsync(); // Success! This contains the values I just set.
}
```

The problem is whenever I upload a new file anywhere inside this folder, the file does not contain the default values that were set with that code. I also looked in the settings located at `/sites/MySite/_layouts/15/ColumnDefaults.aspx` and found the default value column doesn't contain the default values I set even though they come back in that `GetDefaultColumnValuesAsync()` call successfully.

How do I set default column values for a specific folder using the Pnp.Core SDK?

[image: SharePoint Default Folder Settings]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. A subtle thing I missed in the PnP.Core docs for the section on **[Setting default values](https://pnp.github.io/pnpcore/using-the-sdk/lists-intro.html#setting-default-values)** is that the **folder paths are relative to the list and not to the server when setting the FolderRelativeUrl for the individual options.** So make sure your path is correct and that will mitigate the 404 `FileNotFoundException. It's a subtle difference but the naming of the property gives a hint.

[image]

However, I decided to approach it slightly different and just get the existing columns first and then set default values on the folder and updating any values I had for those columns. This allowed me to ignore the paths altogether.

```cs
private async Task SetFolderDefaultValues(IFolder folder, MyData data)
{
    var list = await _sharePointContext.Web.Lists.GetByServerRelativeUrlAsync(folder.ServerRelativeUrl);
    var existingColumns = await list.GetDefaultColumnValuesAsync();

    // Ensure we only have a unique set of columns
    existingColumns = existingColumns.GroupBy(obj => obj.FieldInternalName)
        .Select(group => group.First())
        .ToList();

    foreach (var existingColumn in existingColumns)
    {
        switch (existingColumn.FieldInternalName)
        {
            case "Project_Number": 
                existingColumn.DefaultValue = data.ProjectId;
                break;
            case "Project_Description":
                existingColumn.DefaultValue = data.ProjectName;
                break;
        }
    }

    await list.SetDefaultColumnValuesAsync(existingColumns);
}
```